# Can one get 3 variables from one line of a file? C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Samkelo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Ass2\Ass2\1.txt"))
{

    s = reader.ReadLine();
}

string[] ss = s.Split(':');
if (txtusername.Text == ss[0])
{
if (txtpass.Text == ss[1])
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Hooray");
        taketest ne = new taketest();
        this.Hide();
        ne.Show();

    }
}
```

i have a text file..
details.txt
username,password,fullnames,address

how can i get the address and fullnames after logging in??

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Do not invent your own security